# Set $modelValue without changing $viewValue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In angular 1.2 I need to be able to update the `$modelValue` without affecting the `$viewValue`.  I want the internal value to be one value, while what the user sees to be another.  The problem I am having is setting the `$modelValue` ends up setting the `$viewValue` on the next digest.  My current work-around is using `$timeout` to set the `$viewValue` in the next digest.

```
//...

link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

    //...

    var setter = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign;

    scope.$watch(attrs.otherValue, function(){
        var viewValue = ctrl.$viewValue;
        setter(scope, validate()); // validate returns undefined or value if valid
        $timeout(function(){
            if(ctrl.$viewValue !== viewValue){
                ctrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
                ctrl.$render();
            }
        });
    });

    //...

}

//...
```

Basically, I want to set the internal value of one with when another field changes in Angular 1.2

Fiddle (with ugly `$timeout` workaround): http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/q1s7Lf7z/1/

**TL;DR**
Setting `$modelValue` outside of `$parser`/`$formatter` pipelines changes `$viewValue`, where I am wanted it to only change `$modelValue` (the internal value).

Comment: You should be able to this by pushing a new [$formatters](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$modelValue) on to the model. FWIW, If you update your question with a simple jsfiddle illustrating your current solution then I should be able to get this to work.

Comment: The problem is, the $formatters/$parsers only run when the value is changed. In this case, it is an external value that triggers it. If there a way to trigger the $formatters/$parsers to run?  Also, added fiddle of current solution with ugly `$timeout` workaround.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example, but I am confused why any of this is necessary. I am probably missing something, but when I remove the $timeout portion it seems to behave the exact same way. I guess I just don't understand what the end-goal is...I certainly wasn't expecting password inputs for this.

Comment: It behaves the same most of the time.  It does some odd things when you have a matching value and then change for first field (it clears out the confirm field).  Also, what it is for is https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-input-match

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise in describing your problem? e.g. *Making A and B produces C whereas I am expecting D*

Comment: Ignore the specific workaround stated above for reference, the question is how does one Set `$modelValue` without changing `$viewValue`

Comment: why not create a viewValue and a modelValue? And then update the viewValue when you actually want the user to see the modelValue?

Comment: @Michael I am using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), it has internal values of `$viewValue` and `$modelValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When anything triggers the model to change, something like `setter(scope, validate());` in the example above, it will trigger the `$formatters` to run.  The `$formatters` are passed the `$modelValue` and can return a value that will be used for the `$viewValue`. Knowing this, you can use a simple function that just returns the `$viewValue` in the formatter.  With this, updating the model programmatically will not affect the `$viewValue`, and thus not change the value that appears in `<inputs>`

```
ctrl.$formatters.push(formatter)

function formatter(modelValue){
    return ctrl.$viewValue;
}
```

For the example in the question, you would want to return the `$viewValue` only when the `$modelValue` is `undefined`.  For that you can use this:

```
ctrl.$formatters.push(formatter)

function formatter(modelValue){
    return modelValue === undefined? ctrl.$isEmpty(ctrl.$viewValue)? undefined : ctrl.$viewValue : modelValue;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/q1s7Lf7z/17/