# Persist Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker as string to API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, json.net, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm using angular-ui-datepicker popup and I'm trying to persist the saved date value as a string with the date only. `M/d/yyyy`

The input after date selection is correct `5/11/2015` but the value stored is a `Date`

`Mon May 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 12:00AM`

Is there a way to always store the value as the date `string` and not as a `Date` object?

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" ng-model="event.date"
        is-open="datePickers['date']" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="toggleDatepicker('date', $event)">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

In the above case I need the data to always be the date string, for instance:

```
{
   date: '5/11/2015'
}
```

and not

```
{
   date: `Mon May 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 12:00AM`
}
```

Comment: I would do a custom directive and take advantage of ngModel $formatter to set the $modelValue equal to the $viewValue BUT not do a $render.  Not tested, but this is what I'd try.  See this SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491300/set-modelvalue-without-changing-viewvalue

Comment: Hmm, I need to research more on Angular directives to achieve this it would seem. Any examples of a directive that manipulates the model without affecting how it renders?

Comment: Check the question in my edited comment...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple (standard) JavaScript date formatting function, but I guess you could always build the M/d/yyyy string yourself using for example:

```
getDate() // Returns the date
getMonth() // Returns the month
getFullYear() // Returns the year
```

([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/2592445))

I've also been messing around a bit with this myself on various projects and you might want to consider [Date.toISOString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp). I've found that Angular will automatically deserialize ISO 8601 strings in JSON to an actual Date object for further use and vice versa it'll also serialize date objects to this format transparently, so you don't have to worry about this yourself.

Comment: I know how to format dates but I'm trying to do this automatically using the Angular UI Datepicker

Comment: @hunter Sorry, I see I was unclear but that's what I on about in the latter part of my post. I found that everything works peachy when using Date objects as the model value, so you'd only have to worry about persisting it as a string. It depends on what you mean by persisting, but if you are for example using $http to store/load from a server, it'll automatically convert to/from ISO8601 strings. So if you can live with using a Date object as your model (which seems to be what angular-ui-datepicker requires in the first place), everything should work out automatically already.